# Need a oracle function to conver string to bytes array

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a Column :

```
LOGIN_PWD  ->  RAW(256 BYTE)
```

I have to use a insert query to insert a hashed password string into this column. So is there any oracle function that can covert a string to bytes like

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (LOGIN_PWD) VALUES (convert.toBytes('hashed password'));
```

I did this using java program by using string.getBytes() methode on my local machine but for other env i cant use same program need to do it using query

Comment: Do you mean something like [cast_to_raw](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/u_raw.htm#sthref17499)? I'm not quite sure if you're trying to hash at the same time, or if the value is already hashed.

Comment: yes i mean somehting like cast_to_bytes and value is already hased

Answer (score 13):

If your requirement is as simple as you stated then you can use the [`UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-E837A246-2D2A-47C4-A2F3-29735F596CE1):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (LOGIN_PWD)
VALUES (UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('hashed password'));
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/33c90/2).

With, for example, the plain string 'hashed password' hashed using Md5, which is `6a25a2b265d917ea91447daa81b2506d`, the raw value stored in the table is:

```
SELECT DUMP(LOGIN_PWD) FROM TABLE_NAME;

DUMP(LOGIN_PWD)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=23 Len=32: 54,97,50,53,97,50,98,50,54,53,100,57,49,55,101,97,57,49,52,52,55,100,97,97,56,49,98,50,53,48,54,100
```

Which matches what I get from `getBytes()` on the same hashed value in Java.

If you want to get it back to text for some reason you can use [`UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_RAW.html#GUID-E972F35F-C8EC-4CC2-8EC5-17702E8921D8):

```
SELECT UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(LOGIN_PWD) FROM TABLE_NAME;

UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(LOGIN_PWD)
-----------------------------------
6a25a2b265d917ea91447daa81b2506d
```